# DFA -> regular expression

Tags: regex, state-machine

I've written a DFA on paper, and want to translate it into a set of regular expressions.  Does anybody know a good tool to do this?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you are trying to acheive

Comment: I'm trying to write a parser for sentences that start with a given command like "/dothis" and then have a few parameters after them, depending on the command.  I have written out the DFA with all of the states, but I am looking for a tool that I can use to translate to REGEXP.

Answer (score 6):

From my little google search, I found [JFLAP](http://www.jflap.org/getjflap.html). They also have a tutorial on [how to Convert FA to regular expression](http://www.jflap.org/tutorial/fa/fa2re/index.html#convert).

> **JFLAP**
>
> JFLAP is software for experimenting
>   with formal languages topics including
>   nondeterministic finite automata,
>   nondeterministic pushdown automata,
>   multi-tape Turing machines, several
>   types of grammars, parsing, and
>   L-systems. In addition to constructing
>   and testing examples for these, JFLAP
>   allows one to experiment with
>   construction proofs from one form to
>   another, such as converting an NFA to
>   a DFA to a minimal state DFA to a
>   regular expression or regular grammar.
>   Click here for more information on
>   what one can do with JFLAP.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a parser, there's no need to translate into regular expressions as an intermediate form.  You can code a DFA fairly straightforwardly using `flex` or [`re2c`](http://re2c.org/).  The coding for multiple states is not the common case, so it feels slightly unnatural at first (and it's not well covered in tutorials), but once you get rolling with it, it's really easy.